# If I install Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 6.0 will work or not?

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 6.0
I want to use Visual Studio 2008 also.

I Already Installed the Visual Studio 6.0 (VB6, Foxpro Package) in my system, Now I want to install the Visual Studio 2008(.Net Package). Is Possible to install?

If I install Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 6.0 will work or not?

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use Visual Studio 6.0 side-by side with VS2008. I use this for maintenance of old VB6 code. It is safest to install v6 first, which is what you have done. So install VS2008 and enjoy.

Comment: I recently had to migrate a VB6 project to .NET 3.5. I installed Visual Studio 6.0 after VS 2008 (I didn't originally have any plans to use Visual Studio 6.0) and had to re-associated VS 2008 file extensions. As Mark says it is best to install VS 6.0 first.

Comment: +1 for installing VS6 first. I tried it the other way round and it causes all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 3):

YES. Visual Studio 6.0 will work with Visual Studio 2008 installed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it works, that should be very apparent from the other answers :-)

Maybe one quick tip tho: when you install VS6 it will require the MS Java runtime environment - you **don't** want that! It's an easy fix however: just create an empty file named msjava.dll inside %windir%\System32 and you're off...

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 and then Visual Studio 6.0. Both works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I run VS6, VS2005, and VS2008 on machines here.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Marc Gravell said. first install VB6(VS6) then VS2008 and enjoy.
I already have both VS6 and VS2008 on the same machine